# OpenCV findHomography error

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on a OpenCV project in Java in which I will have to transform an ellipse to circle coordinates on different pictures. I'm doing this by using the findHomograpghy() function since the ellipse contains source points which are more than 4. Currently I have a Mat which contains the points of the ellipse and also another Mat which contains the points of a circle. The ellipse is detected in the image. The circle is created using Imgproc.circle().

I'm basically doing the following:

```
MatOfPoint source_mop = new MatOfPoint(blue_ellipse_contour);
MatOfPoint2f source_points = new MatOfPoint2f(source_mop.toArray());

MatOfPoint dest_mop = new MatOfPoint(cir_contour);
MatOfPoint2f dest_points = new MatOfPoint2f(dest_mop.toArray());
```

Where blue_ellipse_contour and cir_contour are a filled ellipse and circle.

The sizes of the source_points and dest_points differ a bit
      1x3972
      1x3976

I'm doing the following:

```
Mat perspectiveMatrix = calib3d.findHomography(source_points,dest_points);
```

However this returns:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.checkVector(2) == dst.checkVector(2)) in findHomography

I assume this has something to do with the size not being the same. However I currently am a bit lost how to actually find the transformation matrix from a ellipse to a circle? Since the ellipse size and position will differ in the different images.

Any tips will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete code and dataset to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the support, but I kinda got it working. I changed the size of the circle to match with the size of the ellipse and now there is no error :)

Comment: Cool, one request: You can elaborate the question to provide complete info and add your own answer. It will improve your question quality, add a proper answer and will hopefully help anyone else facing this issue.

Comment: I will surely do it when I have perfectioned it myself :)